# Modified erdc - Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \Blinddocument

Tags: packages

I was creating a report using erdc template. I have modified erdc.cls because I don't have the fonts and don't want the hassle to install the non-free font it required.

What I did change inside the erdc.cls are:
 - comment out the font loading: \usepackage{mathgifg} 
 - change every the font style : \fontseries{k} or \fontseries{h} with the more commonly supported b and m.

As substitute/override for the sans font, I load in the preamble section:
 \usepackage{berasans} and \usepackage{mathptmx} for the serif font.

If I compile this simple document:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{erdc}

\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{berasans}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
%   \maketitle
    \Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

I got error report:

> Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \Blinddocument

I could not trace the source of the problem. Please help, my experience in LaTeX are limited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't change a class without changing also its name.

Beside this: the definition of \section in the class is faulty. It uses \addpenalty without ensuring that it is in vertical mode. If you add a `\par` is should work:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{erdc}

\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{berasans}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{%
  \par% added
  \addpenalty\@secpenalty\nobreak
  \secdef\@section\@ssection}
\makeatother  
\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is the answer, thank you so much. BTW, how do you trace to \section, when the log file mislead with "missing \item".

Comment: And thank you for the reminder about the class naming. I have rename the modified  class to erdc-x.cls, and re-install the original.